# Why was my Question About Dithering Closed?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, closed-questions, unanswered-questions

I asked a question called [How do you Render With Foyd-Steinberg Dithering in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268805/how-do-you-render-with-foyd-steinberg-dithering-in-blender), and the question was closed.

Why was the question closed?

How can I fix the question?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be very clear. People asked for clarification in the comments but never got any response, nor was there any additional information edited into your original question.

Comment: As it stands this question seems unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Obviously only you know your exact issue, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe in detail what the issue is, supported by [accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: I find the question understandable, and I've edited it to help others; but the topic is a little obscure and I can see why most people wouldn't understand it.  I've also added a comment with an article that might help the OP.  I'd like the question reopened so I can turn that pointer into an answer with details.

Comment: @MartyFouts reopened, answer away